# Akeneo_I am getting below issue while importing variant products in Akeneo

Tags: akeneo

I have imported product model in Akeneo using import file, Product modes were got created, When I am trying to import variant for that product model I am getting below issue, Anybody can help me please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG4Is.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOPbr.png)

My import files are below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB3ua.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RphV.png)

Thanks
Santosh D

product variants should be created under product model in Akeneo when we import above files.